# How to use the when clause in an ansible task

Tags: python, django, ansible

I have the following in a file for ansible:

```
- name: Run the Django syncdb command
  django_manage:
    command: syncdb
    app_path: '{{ application_path }}'
    virtualenv: '{{ virtualenv_path }}'
    settings: '{{ django_settings_file }}'
  environment: django_environment
  when: run_django_syncdb
  tags: django

- name: Run Django South migrations
  django_manage:
    command: migrate
    app_path: '{{ application_path }}'
    virtualenv: '{{ virtualenv_path }}'
    settings: '{{ django_settings_file }}'
  environment: django_environment
  when: run_django_south_migration
  tags: django
```

When running the following line:

```
$ ansible-playbook development.yml --tags "django"
```

Both of those commands get run. Is there a way to utilize the `when` clause in the line above to have only one of the commands run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would rather work with tags. What you might have missed is that you might pass a list to tags. This would be the usual way to group tasks:

```
- name: Run the Django syncdb command
  django_manage:
    command: syncdb
    app_path: '{{ application_path }}'
    virtualenv: '{{ virtualenv_path }}'
    settings: '{{ django_settings_file }}'
  environment: django_environment
  tags: 
    - django
    - django_sync

- name: Run Django South migrations
  django_manage:
    command: migrate
    app_path: '{{ application_path }}'
    virtualenv: '{{ virtualenv_path }}'
    settings: '{{ django_settings_file }}'
  environment: django_environment
  tags: 
    - django
    - django_south
```

So if you want to run both tasks you call `ansible-playbook development.yml --tags django` or you can call one of the tasks via `ansible-playbook development.yml --tags django_south`

Ramon's answer does also work, but I woul rather prefer my approach due to the following reasons:

- I see variables as machine parameters rather than task parameters. You rather tag the tasks that you want to execute than setting machine parameters (as it might change with every call)
- You will always see `task skipped` in your log file when using conditionals, which is annoying ;)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two variables that are checked if the tasks should be run, `run_django_syncdb` and `run_django_south_migration`.

These can be passed on the call to ansible with `-e`:

```
$ ansible-playbook development.yml --tags "django" -e "run_django_syncdb=true"
$ ansible-playbook development.yml --tags "django" -e "run_django_south_migration=false"
```

The variables you don't mention get set to whatever defaults you have set for them.

If you want to set multiple variables you add them space-separated:

```
$ ansible-playbook development.yml --tags "django" -e "run_django_syncdb=true run_django_south_migration=false"
```